# Why does POST value save empty in database, but var_dumps / echos fine?

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have a contact list that I made with PHP, jQuery and Datatables, where I have inline editing, and as soon as you click outside of a cell it updates via Ajax. Everything about the update of field values work fine, but now I wanted to save who last updated a record, by saving the username from the current session, so I've done that and sent it to the update file as a $_POST, but it won't save. When I dump it out or echo it, I can see the value, so I know it does get posted, but it just won't save in the database and I can't figure out why.

Since I don't code a lot and have learned what I know by reading and copying stuff from Stackoverflow, I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I still need help and I want to learn.

I've tried all kinds of "' variants, and typing in "test" or something in the query or in the variable does save it, so I feel like something is wrong with the $_POST or sql syntax, but since I can dump it and echo it, I have no idea what's wrong.

Worth mentioning is that the first part of the SQL works fine, and updates the cell it's supposed to, so the query runs, but randomly returns either "Uppdaterad!" or "Invaild requests" every other time, but the value saves either way. If I remove the whole "new part" with "last updated by", it works every time and returns "Uppdaterad!" without any problems.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST))
{

    // Database settings
    include "config.php";

    foreach($_POST as $field_name => $val)
    {
        // Clean post values
        $field_contactid = strip_tags(trim($field_name));
        $val = strip_tags(trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $val)));
        $currentuser = strip_tags(trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['currentuser'])));
        //var_dump($currentuser);

        // From the fieldname:contact_id we need to get contact_id
        $split_data = explode(':', $field_contactid);
        $contact_id = $split_data[1];
        $field_name = $split_data[0];

        if(!empty($contact_id) && !empty($field_name))
        {           
        // Update the values
            mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE contactlist SET $field_name = '$val', `last_updated_by` = '$currentuser' WHERE id = $contact_id") or mysqli_error($con);
            //mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE contactlist SET $field_name = '$val' WHERE id = $contact_id") or mysqli_error($con);
            echo "Uppdaterad!";
        } else {
            echo "Invalid Requests";
        }
    }

} else {
    echo "Empty POST!";
}
?>
```

Comment: A few suggestions: You should dump all individual values and check these (post them here) when a query goes wrong and you should switch to a prepared statement so that your values don't get mangled-up by the string functions you are using now. And to close the sql injection problem on the `$contact_id` value... And if you have the username in the session, you should definitely use that and not a user-provided value.

Comment: in some cases the query can be interrupted by a special character for example the apostrophe , check if your data contains it. Or maybe the DB field does not accept the format of the data type that you are trying to insert.

Comment: And very important, you need to whitelist / validate your `$field_name` variables as no escaping or preparing of the statement will fix that sql injection hole.

Comment: Thanks! I finally solved it by using $currentuser = $_SESSION['user_realname']; I only had the user_id in the session previously, but I changed the query and fixed it that way.

Comment: By the way, not sure what you all mean by that sql injection problem... Can someone give me an example? I was assuming since I cleaned the $_POST values it was alright, but clearly I'm missing something. I have no idea what you mean by whitelisting / validation. I guess I should just google it but since I'm here...